# Rails - Cancelling a redirect_to call

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a problem as per another open question I have [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858528/rails-attaching-image-through-paperclip-on-nested-fields-causes-unwanted-unavo) which I just need a quick fix for in the meantime so I can get onto the next bit of the project, and I'll move back to fix this properly later.

I want to know, is there a way in rails to 'cancel' a `redirect_to` action if it was called earlier in a controller method? I don't want to do `redirect_to :nothing`, I just want to make it as if redirect_to wasn't called.

Comment: I don't get it?  If there was a redirect, the control would have changed at that point to the redirect method.  Do you mean you want to know if the current method was reached via redirect as opposed to a direct call? Some sort of if_redirected? kinda thing?

Comment: This may help: http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/03/04/following-redirects-with-nethttp/

Comment: As per my other question I've linked to, I don't call `redirect_to` in my controller action but it still seems to be happening somewhere. I can't find where it's called, so until I can fix the root cause, I just want to remove any changes the redirect_to call makes (from wherever it seems to be happening)

Comment: What do you mean, you "can't find where it's called"? Trace the code.

Comment: I've tried to trace it using debugger, still haven't found it though. Any other suggestions on how to do that?